# How to insert line breaks into Dialog response default values

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

On the final page of a dialog I'm designing I want to have a multiple line text box that acts as a template for what the user has input over the rest of the dialog for them to alter/ add any other comments to create the body for an email. For this I would like to put a line break in between each field to make it a bit more readable.

Any body know how to put the line break in on the default value?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this in standard dialogs. Dialogs are designed to facilitate relatively straightforward data entry scenarios. More sophisticated wizard designs can be built with custom HTML dialogs (using web resources).

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to create one dummy multiline field in entity and set the default value

```
First Line
Second Line
```

and set the default value with this newly created field rather than specifying directly default value.